# ¿Como puedo implementar webview en una aplicacion desarrollada con react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, aplicación-movil

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil en react native para android y ios, implemente webview pero al descargar la aplicación compilada desde el testing de apple que se llama TestFlight, el webview no se renderiza e inhabilita la app, estoy ocupando esta libreria para webview, https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview. Apple me informo que no soporta este tipo de programacion en react native. ¿Como podria implementar un webview alternativo a esta libreria?

Esta es mi función para renderizar el web view. La variable urlFlow solo es un link para poder efectuar un pago mediante tarjetas bancarias.

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const renderWebView = () => {

        if (urlFlow == "") {
            return (
                <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get('screen').height * 0.85 }}>
                    <MostrarSpinner spinner={spinnerActivado} />
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={{
                    width: '100%', height: Dimensions.get('screen').height * 0.82
                }}>
                    <WebView source={{ uri: urlFlow }} style={{ width: '100%', height: Dimensions.get('screen').height * 0.82 }}></WebView>
                </View>
            )
        }

    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo pasar por el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), solo toma dos minutos y te ayuda a saber de manera breve lo que es el sitio de SOEs, seguido de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [un ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del código que has estado empleando, solo links se consideraría una pregunta de baja calidad y corres el riesgo de que sea cerrada o en todo caso, eliminada.

Comment: Me parece muy extraño que te pase esto, yo tengo varias aplicaciones en el Appstore sin ningún problema usando la librería `react-native-webview` e implementandola con un approach similar al tuyo